# I'm trying the change a value from a button to a var every time you click it

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get this to work and I can't think of any way to make this work,
I'm trying to have a button value change to a var every time you press it.

code-

```html
<input onclick="change(this)" type="button" value="0" id="myButton1" />

<script>
  value="1"
 function change(this)
{
target.value = parseInt(target.value) + 1;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `var click + 1` will not work. You need to assign a value to the variable before calculating with declare the variable and using the value 0 to it outside of your functionm

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("myButton1").value=document.getElementById("myButton1").value + 1`, then you don't need the `var`. Although repeating that much code you are better off doing `var button = document.getElementById("myButton1"); button.value = button.value + 1`. But you might run into string conversion here, so also coerce thev value to a number first: `button.value = +button.value + 1`.

Comment: It works but not in the right way all it does is add 1 to the end of it making it 0111 thanks for the help though!

Comment: in the shortest form you can just pass `this` to the change function by doing `onclick="change(this);"` and then have your function use that argument to do `target.value = parseInt(target.value) + 1;` .. that's true as long as you set the value attribute to 0 to begin with in the html `value="1"`

Comment: what is it that you want to do in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the variable outside the function and then increment it inside, otherwise you just reset it every time the function runs.  I would also pass the event into the function so you can change the value of the clicked button rather than getting the element by id each time

```html
<input onclick="change(event)" type="button" value="0" id="myButton1" />

<script>
  // declare variable outside function and set to current value
  var click = parseInt(document.getElementById("myButton1").value, 10);  
               
  function change(e) {
    e.preventDefault();              // if this is in a form, you may want to add this so the form doesn't submit
    click += 1;                      // increment with +=
    e.currentTarget.value = click;   // change value of clicked button
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this it to move the button assignment outside of the function, or just pass `event` and `this` to the inline `onclick` function call.

```html
<input onclick="change(event, this)" type="button" value="0" id="myButton1" />

<script>
  function change(event, button) {
    button.value = +button.value + 1;
  }
</script>
```

You should use `<button type="button">` over `<input type="button">`

If you want a proper; more reusable state handler, you can try:

```js
const applyTemplate = (template, state) =>
  template.replace(/\{(\w+)\}/g, (match, key) =>
    state[key] ?? match);

const updateState = (element, applyState) => {
  const state = JSON.parse(element.dataset.state);
  const template = element.dataset.template;
  const updateState = applyState(state);
  element.dataset.state = JSON.stringify(state);
  element.textContent = applyTemplate(template, state); // Text!
};

const handleClick = ({ target }) => {
  updateState(target, (state) => {
    state.count += 1
  });
};

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('counter')) {
    handleClick(e);
  }
});
```

```html
<button
  type="button"
  class="counter"
  data-state='{ "count": 0 }'
  data-template="Count: {count}"
>
  Count: 0
</button>

<button
  type="button"
  class="counter"
  data-state='{ "count": 0 }'
  data-template="Count: {count}"
>
  Count: 0
</button>

<button
  type="button"
  class="counter"
  data-state='{ "count": 0 }'
  data-template="Count: {count}"
>
  Count: 0
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```js
  let num = 0;
  
  function change() {
    // Increment the variable value
    num++;

    // Update the display with the new value
    document.getElementById('myButton1').value = num;
  }
```

```html
<input onclick="change()" type="button" value="0" id="myButton1" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the variable outside of the function. Here is the code with the fix.

```js
var click = 0;
function change() {
  click = click + 1; // up the var
  document.getElementById("myButton1").value = click;
}
```

```html
<input onclick="change()" type="button" value="click" id="myButton1" />
```

Comment: there is much more wrong then this

Comment: The code works? Yes, it is not the most elegant solution, but it does work.

Comment: what sense make a value on a button? `click = click + 1;` would be simply `click++`. And this is not a `var` scope but a `let` scope